# Sublime Text 3, sidebar items are not showing

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm making a simple plugin for Sublime Text 3, which should create a `.gitignore` file in one or more folders. So far the package contains two commands, which can be called from the ST3 console using `window.command(...)`.

I want to be able to right-click a folder in the sidebar and select a command from the menu that pops up. I've added `Side Bar.sublime-menu` with items to call the methods, but the menu items are not showing when right-clicking a folder or file in the sidebar.

From the info below, does someone know what's missing here?

---

Plugin tree:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/GitIgnoreFolderContents
├── Side\ Bar.sublime-menu
├── git_ignore_folder_contents.py
├── git_ignore_folder_contents.sublime-settings
├── libs
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── util.py
└── notes_use_later.txt
```

Side Bar.sublime-menu:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "-"
    },
    {
        "caption": "Git Ignore Folder Contents",
        "id": "git_ignore_folder_contents",
        "children:": [
            {
                "caption": "Create .gitignore",
                "command": "create_folder_gitignore",
                "args": {
                    "paths": []
                }
            },
            {
                "caption": "Create .gitkeep",
                "command": "create_folder_gitkeep",
                "args": {
                    "paths": []
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

git_ignore_folder_contents.py:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

from .libs.util import print_debug


class BaseCreateFolderIgnoreFileCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, paths=[]):
        print_debug('[GIFC] running {}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
        print_debug('[GIFC] paths:', paths)
        if not paths:
            print_debug('[GIFC] paths is empty, halting function')
            return

        for path in paths:
            # ToDo: create files here
            pass

    def is_enabled(self, paths=[]):
        # ToDo: disable when one of paths is not a folder
        return True


class CreateFolderGitignoreCommand(BaseCreateFolderIgnoreFileCommand):
    filename = '.gitignore'
    contents = '*\n!.gitignore'


class CreateFolderGitkeepCommand(BaseCreateFolderIgnoreFileCommand):
    filename = '.gitkeep'
    contents = ''
```

Environment:

- build 3160 from the dev channel for macOS.
- package "SideBarEnhancements" is installed (among other packages, some with working sidebar menu items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason this isn't working for you is that your `sublime-menu` file is subtly broken; the `children` key has a stray `:` character in it.

In particular, when I create a package with the files you've provided here (same build of Sublime, but on Windows and not MacOS), the top level menu item appears in the menu, but it doesn't have any children as one might expect. Selecting the `Git Ignore Folder Contents` command generates an error in the console. I'm guessing that's because it has no direct `command` to execute since it's not supposed to be selectable.

Fixing this line to not have a colon inside of the key should fix your issue; or at least it does for me:

```json
"children:": [
```

Comment: Hah, I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks a lot! Now excuse me, I'm going to facepalm ;-)

Comment: Haha, if it helps I had to recreate your package and be mystified for a bit before I realized why it wasn't doing what I thought it should. :D